# Text Field doesnt show up in PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am wondering if the following is a known issue and whether there is a solution for it. After searching on google, I could not find anyone with a similar issue.

I am using c#/itextsharp to create a PDF

I've succesfully created about 5 pdfs from 5 different templates that I created; however this one is giving me a lot of [tzaras](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tsuris).

I have a `text field` on the template called `PractitionerName1`.

I am inserting data into it like this:

```
string firstName1 = dr["my:PractitionerFirstName1"].ToString();
            string lastName1 = dr["my:PractitionerLastName1"].ToString();
string fPhysician1 = firstName1 + " " + lastName1;
 cPdf.InsertTextFieldValue("PractionerName1", fPhysician1);
```

doesn't work.

When I create a new text field named `Text1` and do the same exact thing but do:

```
cPdf.InsertTextFieldValue("Text1", fPhysician1);
```

It works.

If I change the name of `Text1` to `PractitionerName1` on the template then it doesn't work.

There is no error message.

What am I doing wrong? how can I correctly insert the data into my `PractitionerName1` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is a typo in your question, but it looks like the name you're using to set the field does not match the field name.

```
cPdf.InsertTextFieldValue("PractionerName1", fPhysician1);
```

should be

```
cPdf.InsertTextFieldValue("PractitionerName1", fPhysician1);
```